# Place SVG in each corner of parent div with css?

Tags: html, css, svg, positioning

I have a div which contains some content, some days it might contain a lot other days almost none. One thing it has every day is 4 svg's corner, independent of the content the svg's should always be in the corners.

My problem is that I cant get them to stay in the right place, when i give them the position absolute attribute they jump "out" of the div.

[Here is an example easy to play around with](https://jsfiddle.net/8vfy0o5e/)

**Here is a picture explaining the request**
[image: Here is a picture explaining the request]

**html**

```
<div style='background-color:#fffff0; text-align-last: center;'>
  <h1>Photos</h1>
  <p>preview</p>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

**css (incomplete/mistaken)**

```
.svgCorner {
  fill:  #ff0000;
  width: 7%;
}

.svgCornerBL{

}

.svgCornerBR{
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.svgCornerTL{
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.svgCornerTR{
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on your parent `div` and use `absolute` positioning with proper `top`, `right`, `bottom` & `left` values, like:

For parent div:

```
<div style='background-color:#fffff0; text-align-last: center; position: relative;'>
  ...
</div>
```

For SVGs:

```
.svgCornerBL{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.svgCornerBR {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.svgCornerTL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.svgCornerTR{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.svgCorner {
  fill:  #ff0000;
  width: 7%;
}

.svgCornerBL{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.svgCornerBR {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.svgCornerTL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.svgCornerTR{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div style='background-color:#fffff0; text-align-last: center; position: relative;'>
  <h1>Photos</h1>
  <p>preview</p>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes exactly what I needed. Was aware about the top, bottom, right, left = 0, but my svg's was flying around out of control.... until "position: relative;" Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes @RasmusPuls. Its my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I have what you need:

```css
.svgCorner {
  fill: #ff0000;
  width: 100%;
}

.svgCornerBL {}

.svgCornerBR {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.svgCornerTL {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.svgCornerTR {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.svg-container-TL {
  width: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.svg-container-TR {
  width: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.svg-container-BL {
  width: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.svg-container-BR {
  width: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style='background-color:#fffff0; text-align-last: center; position: relative; min-height:200px;'>
  <h1>Photos</h1>
  <p>preview</p>
  <div class="svg-container-TL">
    <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0' />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container-TR">
    <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0' />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container-BL">
    <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0' />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="svg-container-BR">
    <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! as I commented on the other answer. that "tiny" position: relative on the parent div made the world of a difference.

Comment: Exactly, it is a great solution when designing